# Faster Compilation - Editor folders for asset store plugins

Tags: unity-game-engine

My projects have a lot of asset store plugins and if i don't move them into the "Standard Assets" folder, to achieve faster compilation times, the whole project compiles really slow.

However, quite a few assets contain their own Editor files, which i believe are stored in separate dynamic libraries in compilation time, thus causing errors if i move their folders into the Standard Assets folder(at least I think that is the reason).

I am wondering, is there a way to handle this so that all the assets are not recompiled and are pretty much part of the Standard Assets folder dll ? The only way i can really think of is to move all the Editor folders content of all the plugins in one location, but i think this is highly likely to produce similarly named files that will overwrite each other and also i am not sure how the asset store would handle asset updates.

Is there a solution to this ? Thanks !

Comment: Im more curious that moving it into Standard Assets changes it.. Which version of unity are you using? unless you clear object/library normally after first compile the compile is a little more incremental (although not entirely which would be way more useful)

Comment: I have 2019.1.7f1. I thought that Unity recompiles everything that is not in the Standard Assets folder from scratch, no ? Unless that has been changed in the most recent versions. I was doing that in earlier versions of Unity and was definitely compiling faster. Right now, I am working on a new project and so I am trying to figure out a way to make it compile faster, cause it is annoying :/ I thought the Standard Assets folder was the de facto way to do so.

Comment: way to go is using Plugins

Comment: @zambari I am getting errors when I move assets that have Editor extensions inside the plugins folder :/

Comment: well everything using the UnityEditor namespace should be in an `Editor` folder ... but such a folder can be also nested anywhere inside the `Plugins` folder ;)

Comment: does it need to be a single folder though ? Cause i am still getting errors for Editor extensions inside the Plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put your third party assets into the **Plugins** folder. ([Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html))

> Always place plug-ins in a folder called Plugins for them to be
>   detected by Unity.
>
> You can only have one Plugins folder and it must be placed in the root
>   of the Project; directly within the Assets folder.

Comment: Would that help with compilation times ? I mean, they get detected anyway, but I want to make compilation faster.

Comment: Also, I still get errors when i put some assets in the plugins folder, probably because they have editor extensions.

Comment: It does help with compilation time as code is compiled into four different assemblies. It would be helpful to see what errors you're getting. My guess is that you're referencing code that is inside a different assembly.

Comment: I think it's because of Editor extensions, because i basically get them when i load an extension from the Unity menus. I think the editor has a different assembly and probably fails to recognize some symbols or so I would think.

Comment: Problem is that a lot of the assets contain editor extensions and so they can't be moved to a Standard Assets or Plugins folder without causing errors in the editor extensions :/

Comment: It’s true that there are extra assemblies for plug-in editor files and another one for project editor files. But I fail to understand what you’re doing wrong, as in my own project I too have plugins and editor extensions that are compiled to different assemblies without errors. Try making a minimal project and see what causes issue.

Comment: So you are moving every asset to the plugins folder and you get no errors, even if they have editor extensions ? If that's the case maybe i need to clean the assemblies or sth, because i did have them on the Standard Assets before moving to the Plugins one.